# ¿Qué significan y cómo son usados "relato", "narrativa" y "correlato" en Chile?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado-en-contexto, extranjerismos, chile, anglicismo

Tengo dudas con el significado de la palabra «correlato» o la frase «tiene un/su/como correlato en» en estos contextos, porque si se busca en un diccionario en español en general sólo se hace alusión a correlación estadística.

- Estos cinco núcleos, presentes a lo largo de toda la obra, **tienen un correlato** en su obra narrativa(=se reflejan, reflecting, clear counterpart,  matching, exact parallel)
- El desempeño de la oferta **tuvo su correlato** en la la aceleración de la actividad(=causa)
- Aquellos son solamente recursos gramaticales, sin **correlato** argumental(=se usan porque sí, sin más)
- La violencia doméstica que se manifiesta en la familia, **tienen su correlato** en la desigualdad de género que es tolerada en el ámbito público(=causa)
- Las exportaciones cayeron en torno al 5% anual, esto por el descenso al 4% de los envíos al exterior. Esto se explicó por los problemas técnicos que afectaron al sector y que **tuvieron como correlato** una incidencia negativa sobre el PIB.(=como resultado, economic output, result)
- Relaciono algunos de sus poemas con los artículos en prosa que ella escribió sobre otras mujeres, ya que **veo un claro correlato** entre ambos, particularmente aquellos que pertenecen aquel ciclo(=relación, correlate, closely bound up)
- **Debido a su correlato** de actividad delictiva no es fácil de controlar(antecedentes, background, related direct)
- El miedo a morir **tiene un correlato biológico** de supervivencia(=sustento, explicación, support)
- Él **estableció un correlato** entre su ausencia y una posible infidelidad(=asumir, correlate)

Con todo esto entiendo que con «correlato» se refiere en general a mirar hacia atrás y encontrar puntos en común.

Además me preguntaba si 'su' es más coloquial o es tan standard como 'un'.

P.D: No confundir con «relato», que es la forma en como alguien construye su «narrativa».

---

EDIT: "**(No) tiene relato**" lo dicen políticos, académicos, periodistas, comentaristas deportivos o relatores, profesores de literatura, sociólogos, etc en Chile para decir que hay una narrativa de base, pero la definición de narrativa en español es muy diferente de la palabra en inglés **narrative**, ésta engloba conceptos, hilvana y trata de responder preguntas básicas como: Desde venimos, como se han estado haciendo las cosas, quiénes somos, en que estamos ahora y que queremos mirando hacia el futuro, una suerte de bagaje, estructura colectiva, pilar, troncal, identidad histórica que representa por ejemplo las decisiones que se van a tomar y que proveen de un sentido, norte u orientación.

---

EDIT2: Otro ejemplo de su uso es el de fuerzas antagónicas en las cuales cada una tiene una visión y según la efervescencia del momento una prevalece por sobre la otra, ya sea por ser mayoritaria o por imposición, entonces p.ej. se dice que "**cambió el relato**", es decir, "un cambio de dirección de acuerdo a los acontecimientos", "un cambio la postura", "se dió un giro debido a", "cambio la forma de contar las cosas y de justificar las nuevas acciones", "debido a un mal resultado opera un mecanismo de autoconvencimiento que gatilla un cambio de rumbo", "" etc. Se hacen comparaciones entre un suceso contingente con un determinado momento histórico de p.ej. hace décadas, cuando irónicamente hace unas semanas ese relato era completamente diferente, p.ej. al relato que surgió o que impuso el presidente que vino después de la revuelta de hace un siglo o de tal o cual movimiento, proceso, revolución o dictadura.

---

EDIT3: Entonces la definición de la rae de **relato**:

> 3. m. Reconstrucción discursiva de ciertos acontecimientos interpretados en favor de una ideología o de un movimiento político"

Sería similar a por.ej a lo expuesto por [Marshall Ganz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_Ganz)

¿Y entonces correlato sólo estaría ligado a las definiciones de correlación?

Y, **narrativa** en español es algo diferente:

> 2. f. Género literario constituido por la novela, la novela corta y el cuento. –

> **narrative** /ˈnarətɪv/ noun. b) a way of presenting or understanding a situation or series of events that reflects and promotes a particular point of view or set of values –

[Elecciones en Chile y su **relato** en Colombia: A veces la indignación no es suficiente que hayan quedado por fuera justamente los candidatos de centro es un correlato de que más que de izquierdas o de derechas, el electorado chileno esté virando hacia una posición mayoritariamente opositora a las formas tradicionales de hacer política y antiélites. Según la última encuesta del Latinobarómetro, el 86% de los chilenos consideran que “se gobierna para un grupo de poderosos” y no para la mayoría.](https://www.pares.com.co/post/elecciones-en-chile-y-su-relato-en-colombia-a-veces-la-indignaci%C3%B3n-no-es-suficiente)

> Una decisión que dejará varios daños colaterales en un gobierno que está redefiniendo su **relato** al perder uno de los pilares transformadores que era la Constitución

> El colonialismo triunfante construyó un **relato** de una nación compuesta por un solo pueblo, confinando lo indígena a los márgenes del Estado, y a los relatos folclóricos y heroicos de un pasado ancestral. Todas estas normas tienen un correlato en los derechos de los pueblos indígenas en el Derecho internacional, presentes en los tratados e instrumentos que Chile ha suscrito y en las múltiples experiencias comparadas en diversos países del mundo.

> “Entonces ¿Para qué se hace? Para entregarle más garantías a las transnacionales y para limitar las políticas de desarrollo de este país y a mí, me parece tremendamente delicado, que una coalición de gobierno que ya lo votó en contra -porque lo votaron en contra en la Cámara cuando los que están en el gobierno eran diputados- nuevamente cambien de **relato** y nuevamente crean que es bueno para Chile poder impulsarlo”.

Comment: En Chili, o qualquer país de habla española, relato es una narrativa. *correlato* es igual en todas variedades del español. "Cambió el relato" quire decir que la narrativa cambió. Más un lenguaje es formal, más el espanhol *no cambia*.

Comment: Entonces la definición de la rae "3. m. Reconstrucción discursiva de ciertos acontecimientos interpretados en favor de una ideología o de un movimiento político" sería similar a por.ej a lo expuesto por [Marshall Ganz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_Ganz) y correlato sólo estaría ligado a las definiciones de correlación?

Comment: narrative /ˈnarətɪv/ noun. b) a way of presenting or understanding a situation or series of events that reflects and promotes a particular point of view or set of values

Comment: @Lambie Porque narrativa en español es algo diferente: 2. f. Género literario constituido por la novela, la novela corta y el cuento.

Comment: Hay muchos artículos que comienzan hablando de narrativa como género literario y terminan dándole el significado de discurso, aunque no creo que sean estrictamente excluyentes.

Comment: No he dicho que narrativa es algo diferente. He dicho: [en] qualquer país de habla española, relato es una narrativa.

Answer (score 1):

El DLE define [correlato](https://dle.rae.es/correlato) como

1. m. Término que corresponde a otro en una correlación.

Esto no se limita a la definición estadistica. Las dos definiciones relevantes de [correlación](https://dle.rae.es/correlaci%C3%B3n) son:

1. f. Correspondencia o relación recíproca entre dos o más cosas o series de cosas.
2. f. Estad. Medida de la tendencia de la evolución de dos variables.

Es decir, si dos cosas están correladas (si los cambios en una provocan cambios en la otra), entonces cada una de esas dos cosas es un *correlato*.

Parece que en la mayoría de las frases de la pregunta, esta definición se toma en un sentido amplio y se usa *correlato* como sinónimo de "causa" o "consecuencia", lo cual no es necesariamente incorrecto porque una variable o evento suelen estar correlados con sus causas o consecuencias (correlación no implica causalidad, pero causalidad suele implicar correlación).

Sí que pienso que una de las frases es incorrecta, concretamente

> Relaciono algunos de sus poemas con los artículos en prosa que ella escribió sobre otras mujeres, ya que veo un claro correlato entre ambos, particularmente aquellos que pertenecen aquel ciclo.

Aquí, se usa *correlato* como sinónimo de *correlación*, lo cual es incorrecto (no aparece como significado en el DLE). Sería mejor usar la palabra *correlación* en esta frase.

Comment: Del mismo texto, repite mucho esa palabra:
Nuevos ejemplos de este correlato entre su ensayo y su poesía lo encontramos en el poema ―La bailarina‖:
De todas formas, como he podido comprobar a lo largo de esta investigación, hay un correlato claro de su visión de la mujer artista de su prosa con la de su poesía.

Comment: Creo que en este caso se usa como para decir que hay una similitud, un símil, puntos en común. O como para decir que constantemente su obra actual tiene reminiscencias a sus obras anteriores. Y creo que en otros casos se usa como comodín.

Answer (score 1):

Me da la sensación de que entre los diccionarios que mencionas no has consultado nuestro diccionario de cabecera, el DLE, donde no se hace mención a la estadística.

[**correlato, ta**](https://dle.rae.es/correlato)

> 1. m. Término que corresponde a otro en una **correlación**.

[**correlación**](https://dle.rae.es/correlaci%C3%B3n)

> 1. f. Correspondencia o **relación recíproca** entre dos o más cosas o series de cosas.

**[relación](https://dle.rae.es/relaci%C3%B3n)**

> 1. f. Exposición que se hace de un hecho.
> 2. f. **Conexión**, correspondencia de algo con otra cosa.

> 5. f. Lista de nombres o elementos de cualquier clase.

[**recíproco, ca**](https://dle.rae.es/rec%C3%ADproco)

> 1. adj. Igual en la correspondencia de uno a otro.

Ahí arriba tienes las palabras y sus significados más relevantes. La palabra **correlato** sirve para señalar los elementos implicados en una **correlación**, que es una **relación recíproca**, donde cada uno de los elementos implicados influye en los demás; es decir, si A está correlacionado con B es porque A influye en B y B influye en A.

En la mayoría de tus ejemplos la reciprocidad se obvia, se omite, y se emplea - de forma errónea, en mi opinión - la palabra **correlato** para señalar algún tipo de **vínculo** o conexión entre dos elementos, esas relaciones de causa-efecto que señalas. En resumen, se emplea correlato como sinónimo de relación, cuando NO lo es.

Se establece esta igualdad de términos
correlato = correlación = relación = vínculo

Llegándose al extremo ya de establecer esta otra que para mí tiene aún menos sentido
correlato = correlación = relación = lista de elementos

> Debido a su correlato de actividad delictiva no es fácil de controlar

¿Qué es un correlato de actividad delictiva? ¿Los antecedentes penales de alguien? ¿Cuál es el otro término de la correlación?

Comment: A eso mismo me refería que de inmediato se encuentran definiciones de lógica. Quiere decir que hay antecedentes que en el pasado de que esa actividad a sido difícil de controlar en en esa región o en otras regiones debido a las ganancias inmediatas que permite, ya hay un antecedente, un historial con el cual comparar la actual situación o hacer nexos y generar un plan de contingencia. Eso en el ámbito periodístico y jerga policial o del hampa. También lo he visto usado en grámatica, filosofía y literatura y ni siquiera lo he analizado porque creo que no se relaciona con nada.

Comment: @cocteau Mis preguntas finales eran retóricas. Esa es tu interpretación de la frase, y puede ser acertada, pero no se corresponde con el significado de la palabra "correlato", en mi opinión es un mal uso de ella. Insisto, "correlato de actividad delictiva" no es nada, no se puede inferir de la frase cuál es el correlato. Quizás el autor quería decir "Debido a la enmarañada red de actividades delictivas no es fácil de controlar". NO significa un antecedente, ni un histórico, ni un archivo de actividades delictivas previas. Esos significados no aparecen en los términos que he citado arriba.

Comment: Todo esto no tiene nada que ver con Chile. Las dos palabras tienen el mismo signaficado en todos los paises de habla española.